# Can not setText of ArrayString from taking position of another Arraystring nested in spinner

Tags: android, arraylist, android-spinner

I am coding a calculation app and I want users to select an item from materialNames arraylist (Adapter of spinner). So in spinner I will get the position and take the related value in same position in other arraylist which is called allowableStress. After that I want to display that value in Textview (allowableStressText). However with below code I was not able to achieve my purpose. Could you please check weather there is something wrong in my coding logic or not.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView allowableStressText;
    String allowableStressValue;
    String spinnerValue;
    ArrayList<String> allowableStress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        allowableStressText = findViewById(R.id.allowableStressText);


        //Spinner kodu başlıyor.
        Spinner spinnerMaterial = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMaterial);

        //Material Spinner için data kaynağı
        ArrayList<String> materialNames = new ArrayList<>();

        materialNames.add("Other Material than listed");
        materialNames.add("API5L A25 Pipe Type: BW, ERW, S");
        materialNames.add("API5L A Pipe Type: ERW, S, DSA");
        materialNames.add("API5L B Pipe Type: ERW, S, DSA");
        materialNames.add("API5L X42 Pipe Type: ERW, S, DSA");
        materialNames.add("API5L X46 Pipe Type: ERW, S, DSA");

        allowableStress = new ArrayList<>();

        allowableStress.add("Enter SMYS value");
        allowableStress.add("172");
        allowableStress.add("207");
        allowableStress.add("241");
        allowableStress.add("290");
        allowableStress.add("317");

         ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, materialNames);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinnerMaterial.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class SpinnerActivity extends MainActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){

                 spinnerValue = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                 allowableStressValue = allowableStress.get(Integer.parseInt(spinnerValue));
                 allowableStressText.setText(allowableStressValue);
            }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a material", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: where is the `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` method?

Comment: what does do the spinnerActivity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `onItemSelectedListener` try with this on you `onCreate` method:

```
    spinnerMaterial.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerMaterial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            spinnerValue = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            allowableStressValue = allowableStress.get(Integer.parseInt(spinnerValue));
            allowableStressText.setText(allowableStressValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This code piece has solved my issue with a tiny change. By using the code as it is, app gives fatal error. So I deleted spinnerValue and only write parent.getItemAtPosition(position) and than use only position in parenthesis for following two lines.